# Extract sequence of rows based on conditions and constraints

Tags: r, dplyr

In this data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(Line = 1:16,
Speaker = c(NA, "ID01.A", NA, "ID01.C", NA, "ID01.A", "ID01.C", NA, "ID01.A", NA, 
            "ID01.C", "ID01.A", NA, "ID01.C", NA, "ID01.B"), 
Utterance = c("(5.127)", "how old's your mom¿", "(0.855)", "eh six:ty:::-one=", "(0.101)", 
              "=yeah (...) yeah yeah", "[(...)]", "(0.202)", "she's not like in the (.) <!risk! age group>", "(1.452)", "°ye[a:h]°", 
              "[HH.]", "(0.347)", "°I don't know°", "(0.478)", "yeah I talked to my grandparents"), 
size_temp = c(NA, 12L, 12L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 9L)), 
row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I need to **extract sequences of rows based on conditions**:

- extract rows where `size_temp` is `>= 3 & <= 25` but *do not extract rows with multiple different* `size_temp` values
- extract the **single** immediately following row (whatever `size_temp`)

and number the Sequences consecutively.

My **(imperfect) solution** so far:

a. Define function to extract sequence:

```
Sequence_fn <- function(size) {
  inds <- which(size %in% 3:25 & lead(size)) 
  sort(unique(c(inds, inds + 1)))  
}
```

b. Apply function:

```
df %>%
  slice(Sequence_fn(size = size_temp)) %>%
  mutate(Sequ = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.numeric(Line)) > 1)))
# A tibble: 12 × 5
    Line Speaker Utterance                                    size_temp  Sequ
   <int> <chr>   <chr>                                            <int> <int>
 1     2 ID01.A  how old's your mom¿                                 12     1
 2     3 NA      (0.855)                                             12     1
 3     4 ID01.C  eh six:ty:::-one=                                    2     1
 4     6 ID01.A  =yeah (...) yeah yeah                                3     2
 5     7 ID01.C  [(...)]                                              3     2
 6     8 NA      (0.202)                                              3     2
 7     9 ID01.A  she's not like in the (.) <!risk! age group>        14     2
 8    10 NA      (1.452)                                             14     2
 9    11 ID01.C  °ye[a:h]°                                            1     2
10    14 ID01.C  °I don't know°                                       4     3
11    15 NA      (0.478)                                              4     3
12    16 ID01.B  yeah I talked to my grandparents                     9     3
```

The solution is imperfect as the algorithm keeps extracting over different `size_temp` values when they are within the specified range. Also, when a row is extracted as the single immediately following row and falls within the specified `size_temp` range, this row should be **repeated** (as it then forms the beginning of a new `Sequ`).

So the **expected result** would be this:

```
# Line Speaker Utterance                                        size_temp     Sequ
# <int> <chr>   <chr>                                               <int>     <int> 
#  2     ID01.A  how old's your mom¿                                 12        1
#  3     NA      (0.855)                                             12        1
#  4     ID01.C  eh six:ty:::-one=                                    2        1
#  6     ID01.A  =yeah (...) yeah yeah                                3        2
#  7     ID01.C  [(...)]                                              3        2
#  8     NA      (0.202)                                              3        2
#  9     ID01.A  she's not like in the (.) <!risk! age group>        14        2
#  9     ID01.A  she's not like in the (.) <!risk! age group>        14        3
# 10     NA      (1.452)                                             14        3
# 11     ID01.C  °ye[a:h]°                                            5        3
# 11     ID01.C  °ye[a:h]°                                            5        4
# 12     ID01.A  [HH.]                                                5        4
# 13     NA      (0.347)                                              5        4
# 14     ID01.C  °I don't know°                                       4        5
# 15     NA      (0.478)                                              4        5
# 16     ID01.B  yeah I talked to my grandparents                     9        5
```

Comment: This is a little confusing to me, Chris. (1) I think by "extract" you mean "remove" and keep the rest, right? (2) "Rows with multiple different" to me suggests there should be a grouping variable. (3) Why are lines 9 and 11 duplicated?

Comment: By 'extract' I mean extract/filter and remove the rest. The grouping variable is `size_temp`. Lines 9 and 11 are duplicated because they are both what I call the single immediately following row *and* the beginning of a new `Sequ`ence

Comment: "extract"; got it, thanks for the clarification. If you group by `size_temp`, then you will never see "multiple different values" within a group, perhaps we're talking about different things?